# How to assign value to variable in angular subscribe method

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I have a service that will use angularfire to get data from firestore.
Once i get the data i wish to assign the value to a global variable like this.currentQuantity.
But the value for this.currentQuantity is getting undefine outside the subscribe() method while getting correct within the subscribe method.

my component.ts file

```
onBuy(){
 this.stockService.GetOverviewStock().subscribe((response) => {
      response.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.StockName == this.selectedStockName) {
          this.currentQuantity = item.Quantity;
          this.currentTotalMoneySpent = item.TotalMoneySpent;
        }
        console.log(this.currentQuantity) // correct value from firestore
      });
    });

 console.log(this.currentQuantity) // undefine
...doSomething(this.currentQuantity) // the value is undefine
}
```

My service.ts file that get data from firestore.

```
  GetOverviewStock() {
    return this.firestore
      .collection<StockModel>("OverviewStock", (ref) => ref.orderBy("StockName", "asc"))
      .valueChanges();
  }
```

Help, I am new to angular and do not really understand why and how to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Observables` are new way of handling `async` requests. Subscriptions to `Observables` are quite similar to calling a `function`. But where `Observables` are different is in their ability to return multiple values called `streams`.Observables not only able to return a value synchronously, but also asynchronously.

In your case first the second `console.log(this.currentQuantity)` is executed which is not initialized with the `subscription` and because of that you get `undefine` first and then your `subscription` evaluated. You can try this:

**app.component.ts**

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.stockService.GetOverviewStock().subscribe((response) => {
      response.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.StockName == this.selectedStockName) {
          this.currentQuantity = item.Quantity;
          this.currentTotalMoneySpent = item.TotalMoneySpent;
        }
        console.log(this.currentQuantity) // correct value from firestore
        this.logObservable();
      });
  });
}

logObservable() {
  console.log(this.currentQuantity)
}
```

Here `this.logObservable()` is out of the subscription and if you check it the answer is correct. So you should consider the `async` behavior and do something like this.

Comment: thank it work half the point. In the logObservable() i have call below function to insert document into firestore. but it have result in looping for dont know what reason.
this.firestore.collection("OverviewStock").doc("test").set(
        {
          StockName: "test",
          Quantity: this.currentQuantity,
        },
        { merge: true }
      );

Comment: What do you mean by loop? What's the problem clearly? If you want just `insert` into `firebase` after a subscription you can just do it inside the `.subscribe()` or like the example call another function. Each time that you get a data from your observable, the function will call. maybe you have multi event form your observable.

Answer (score 0):

It will work as expected, except that `GetOverviewStock()` must fire even first (so subscription and value assignment is called). Initially, those fields will be undefined indeed (or have other initial value that you have set)

Comment: sorry, i dont really get you. my code logic is i will first call the GetOverviewStock() to retrieve the value from firestore. Once i get the value i assign to currentQuantity as below there will be other function to run. However i am getting undefined

Comment: But you are first printing the value and then you are later on you are assinging it. You must understand thay you are using async code here (actually, callback that is invoced asynchronously) Therefore, first you log to console, later on you receive event and makes assignments

Answer (score 0):

You're using async, so you have to call `...doSomething(this.currentQuantity)` inside the `subscribe()` (like @ng-hobby said). In short, you cannot get `this.currentQuantity` value outside the `subscribe()` like your code, you can read more about async call to understand why.